# OS memory isolation

Tags: operating-system, virtualization, hypervisor

I am trying to write a very thin hypervisor that would have the following restrictions:

- runs only one operating system at a time (ie. no OS concurrency, no hardware sharing, no way to switch to another OS)
- it should be able **only** to isolate some portions of RAM (do some memory translations behind the OS - let's say I have 6GB of RAM, I want Linux / Win not to use the first 100MB, see just 5.9MB and use them without knowing what's behind)

I searched the Internet, but found close to nothing on this specific matter, as I want to keep as little overhead as possible (the current hypervisor implementations don't fit my needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions / hints, which are necessarily somewhat incomplete, as developing a from-scratch hypervisor is an involved task.

Make your hypervisor "multiboot-compliant" at first.  This will enable it to reside as a typical entry in a bootloader configuration file, e.g., /boot/grub/menu.lst or /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

You want to set aside your 100MB at the *top* of memory, e.g., from 5.9GB up to 6GB.  Since you mentioned Windows I'm assuming you're interested in the x86 architecture.  The long history of x86 means that the first few megabytes are filled with all kinds of legacy device complexities.  There is plenty of material on the web about the "hole" between 640K and 1MB (plenty of information on the web detailing this).  Older ISA devices (many of which still survive in modern systems in "Super I/O chips") are restricted to performing DMA to the first 16 MB of physical memory.  If you try to get in between Windows or Linux and its relationship with these first few MB of RAM, you will have a lot more complexity to wrestle with.  Save that for later, once you've got something that boots.

As physical addresses approach 4GB (2^32, hence the physical memory limit on a basic 32-bit architecture), things get complex again, as many devices are memory-mapped into this region.  For example (referencing the other answer), the IOMMU that Intel provides with its VT-d technology tends to have its configuration registers mapped to physical addresses beginning with 0xfedNNNNN.

This is doubly true for a system with multiple processors.  I would suggest you start on a uniprocessor system, disable other processors from within BIOS, or at least manually configure your guest OS not to enable the other processors (e.g., for Linux, include 'nosmp' 
 on the kernel command line -- e.g., in your /boot/grub/menu.lst).

Next, learn about the "e820" map.  Again there is plenty of material on the web, but perhaps the best place to start is to boot up a Linux system and look near the top of the output 'dmesg'.  This is how the BIOS communicates to the OS which portions of physical memory space are "reserved" for devices or other platform-specific BIOS/firmware uses (e.g., to emulate a PS/2 keyboard on a system with only USB I/O ports).

One way for your hypervisor to "hide" its 100MB from the guest OS is to add an entry to the system's e820 map.  A quick and dirty way to get things started is to use the Linux kernel command line option "mem=" or the Windows boot.ini / bcdedit flag "/maxmem".

There are a lot more details and things you are likely to encounter (e.g., x86 processors begin in 16-bit mode when first powered-up), but if you do a little homework on the ones listed here, then hopefully you will be in a better position to ask follow-up questions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for already exists, in hardware!

It's called IOMMU[1]. Basically, like page tables, adding a translation layer between the executed instructions and the actual physical hardware.

AMD calls it IOMMU[2], Intel calls it VT-d (please google:"intel vt-d" I cannot post more than two links yet).

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOMMU 
[2] http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/892006101.aspx